# how to avoid that=this on JS using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

This is my client JS script

```
var Chat = function(username) {

    that = this;            
    this.myUser = {"username":username};    
    this.socket = io(server);

    this.socket.on('connect', function(){   
        console.log(that.myUser);   // this is UGLY but this.myUser will give an error  
    });
}
```

any idea of how to get rid of that nasty "that = this" ?

Comment: use `self = this`... (just kidding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var Chat = function(username) {

    this.myUser = {"username":username};    
    this.socket = io(server);

    this.socket.on('connect', function(){   
        console.log(this.myUser);
    }.bind( this ) );
};
```

But to be honest, I personally do not think, that this is much better.

Comment: @jfriend00 Good point ... to hasty an answer ...

Comment: I suppose that I might ask why creating the closure on 'that' is such a bad or ugly thing?

Comment: @LeviBeckman I think both approaches are valid. Personally I use both based on the contents of the callback.